# Jberet, manually set writecount on batchlet

Tags: java, jsr352, jberet, jbatch

I wonder if is possible to manually set *writecount* property on a batchlet in order to log result on *STEP_EXECUTION.WRITECOUNT* field's table.

This is my pseudo code

```
@Inject
EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
private Logger logger;


@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public void executeQuery(String query) {

    final int output = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();

    logger.info("rows updated: {}", output);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to do similar stuff and am missing appropriate support in the JSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STEP_EXECUTION.WRITECOUNT` column in the table is not applicable to a batchlet step. If you set data to it, it will still be meaningless. But I think if you somehow set this value in your batchlet, it will be persisted to the job repository.

Comment: Hmmm, this answer sounds a lot different to my similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196371/4222206