# JBeret - Batchlet Metrics not supported?

Tags: metrics, jberet

While I started using JBeret being the embedded JSR-352 engine in Wildfly, I notice that for some of my workload the chunk pattern does not apply. Simple enough I just wrapped it into batchlets and they are running ok.

Now I'd like to collect metrics the same style as chunks do but there seems no method to

- increase existing metrics
- introduce new metrics

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batchlet is used to model task that is a single unit of work. If your workload is iterative in nature and needs collecting metrics as it progresses, you'll need to use chunk-based step.

Comment: I believe this view is a bit narrow minded.
Yes, I need to iterate over entries, however in my case for some of them I'd have to write multiple other items, while for some others there is no work to do.
So the Reader/Writer pattern does not match for me.

But your answer does not explain why batchlets should not be able to fill metrics.

Comment: [MetricType](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/batch/runtime/Metric.MetricType.html) defines a list of supported metrics. None of them applies to batchlet type step.  A batchlet step, once started, runs to the end (unless stopped), and there is no chance to collect such metrics.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. So I understand JSR-352 supports read/process/write patterns very well and everything else is not supported. For batchlets I need to invent my own way of collecting metrics - in that case I can do that for the chunk based steps as well. The specification might need a rework.